# Add a ruby variable to javascript in htnl.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have internal javascript written in an html.erb file in my rails project.

```
<!-- walkscript.html.erb -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 var user_login = '<%= current_user.try(:login) %>';
  (function() {
    var walkme = document.createElement('script');
    walk.type = 'text/javascript';
    walk.async = true;
    walk.src = ''
  })();
</script>
```

And I am using the `settingslogic` gem for settings solution in my project, which accesses the settings as Settins.setting_name in my project.
I have a setting in my application.yml by the name `js_url`.
How do I add it to the walk.src in my html.erb file ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ERB tags, just like you do for `user_login`

`walk.src = "<%= Settings.js_url %>"`